# Cannot resolve method findViewByID(int) fragment java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

Errors on:  updated

Tried to use `GetView.findViewById` error cannot resolve method `GetView`
tried to use just `findViewById` error cannot resolve `findViewById(int)`

```js
package com.example.user.myapplication.Tabs;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.user.myapplication.R;

public class Hotel extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    LinearLayout mLinearLayoutHeader;
    ValueAnimator mAnimator;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.hotel_frag,container,false);
        return v;

       mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        //mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mLinearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.header);

        //Add onPreDrawListener
        mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        mLinearLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                        mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                        return true;
                    }
                });


        mLinearLayoutHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mLinearLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    expand();
                }else{
                    collapse();
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    private void expand() {
        //set Visible
        mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  /* Remove and used in preDrawListener
  final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  mLinearLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

  mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
  */

        mAnimator.start();
    }

    private void collapse() {
        int finalHeight = mLinearLayout.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

        mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                //Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
                mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
            }
        });
        mAnimator.start();

    }


    private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);


        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                //Update Height
                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mLinearLayout.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = value;
                mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }
}
```

Comment: `findViewById` is not method of `Fragment` class use  `View` object to access `findViewById` method. like in `mLinearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
`line use `mLinearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayou) v .findViewById(R.id.header);`

Comment: So What method should i be using? How do i use View object to access findview

Comment: Use `v` which u are returning from `onCreateView` method

Comment: Doesn't seems working :/

Comment: edit and update your code and we will tell you why it isn't working..

Comment: Updated my code . :l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.expandable);
```

and 'return v' should be the last line in your onCreateView method

Ur method should look like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.hotel_frag,container,false);

   mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.expandable);
    //mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mLinearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.header);

    //Add onPreDrawListener
    mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    mLinearLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                    return true;
                }
            });


    mLinearLayoutHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mLinearLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                expand();
            }else{
                collapse();
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Tried the method Isn't working as well "Unreachable Statement on my mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.expandable);

Comment: remove return v call in the second line.. i have updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

Please give return statement at the end of oncreate method.

```
    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.hotel_frag,container,false);

----------------- your code -----------------

            return v;
}
```

Comment: thank you my friend you've just saved my life ... this answer should be marked as the best answer ... :D